# Atmel AVR languages

Tags: atmega328

Hello I recently purchased some atmel AVR chips. You can programme them in Arduino. I was wondering if it is possible to programme them in any other language except for C or Arduino. Also can you use just binary instead of C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if it is possible to programme them in any other language except for C or Arduino.

I have seen this question before. Here is a great answer with a lot of links:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590161/programming-languages-targeting-arduino-avr

There are also a number of libraries/platforms/frameworks as the Arduino core to help you up from "bare metal".

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can program them in C or C++ through the avr-gcc compiler. Arduino uses C++ ([-std=gnu++11](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/platform.txt#L30)) and automatically includes a few libraries, as well as generating forward declarations for anything in the top level .ino file automatically.

You can write AVR assembly and translate it to machine code using avr-as (a portion of avr-gcc)

There is nothing stopping you from just writing whatever bytes you want to program memory if you want to write machine code.

You can look through the [avr instruction set](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-0856-avr-instruction-set-manual.pdf) if you are interested in those last two options.